# Does FileVault prompt for passwords more often?

Tags: macos, password, filevault

If I enable FileVault on Mountain Lion, will it make my machine ask me for my password more often?

For example, right now I have my machine configured so that when it goes to sleep, if I wake it up within 15 minutes, I don't need to enter my password when I wake it up.  Can I still do that, if I enable FileVault?  Or will FileVault force me to enter my password every time I wake up my machine, period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will not prompt you for your password when it wakes up unless you have that selected in the "Security" pane in System Preferences. I've had FileVault enabled for as long as I've had my Macbook, and I don't believe that it has asked me for my password once except for when I was first setting it up.